# Have an element with 2 CSS Animations executing at the same time

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

I am experimenting with WebKits animations.

**Is it possible for a HTML element to have more than one animation executing at the same time?**

For example:

```
    @-webkit-keyframes FADE 
    {
       from {
          opacity: 0;
       }
       to {
          opacity: 1;
       }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes TRICKY 
    {
       0% {
          -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0) rotate(-5deg) skew(-15deg,0);
       }
       50% {
          -webkit-transform: translate(-100px,0) rotate(-15deg) skew(-25deg,0);
       }
       75% {
          -webkit-transform: translate(-200px,0) rotate(-5deg) skew(-15deg,0);
       }
       100% {
          -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0) rotate(0) skew(0,0);
       }
    }

// Can this element have FADE execute for 5 seconds BUT halfway between that animation
// can I then start the TRICKY animation & make it execute for 2.5 seconds?
#myEle {
    -Webkit-animation-name: FADE TRICKY;
    -Webkit-animation-duration: 5s 2.5s;
}
```

The above was a really simple example. I would have many libraries of animations such as rotate, fade, etc. And I dont want to have to write a special animation if I want to have an element execute 2 animations at the same time.

Is this possible...

```
//Not sure if this is even valid CSS: can I merge 2 animations easily like this?
@-webkit-keyframes FADETRICKY
{
   FADE TRICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 32):

```
#myEle {
    -Webkit-animation-name: FADE,TRICKY;
    -Webkit-animation-duration: 5s,2.5s;
}
```

Use ',' no space.  I was in Chrome version 16.0.899.0 to try.

Comment: Also, `-webkit-animation: FADE 5s,TRICKY 2.5s` works.  I swear I tried this a long time ago.  Either I screwed up or it wasn't supported when I tried :)  http://jsfiddle.net/ALBDe/

Comment: Comma-separating the animations worked for me.  Is it possible to assign an animation to one css selector and another animation to another selector and then combine those classes on an element, like <div class="fade-in change-color"></div>?  Not working for me in Chrome 22 beta, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I'd like to present should not achieve them, `-webkit-animation-name` attribute will be overwritten

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to manually merge the animations, I think.

If you need to use something like this in several places I'd take a look at [Less CSS](http://lesscss.org/) or similar, so that you can use "mixins" (e.g. functions) to generate css. I use it for abstracting vendor specific css so that in the main .less file 5 or 6 lines of browser specific code can be replaced by one method.